# Class function that returns a pointer to itself while being const. c++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Here's what I've tried:

```
game* Reversi::clone() const{
    Reversi* ptr = this;
    return ptr;
}
```

But I receive the following error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const Reversi*’ to ‘Reversi*’ [-fpermissive]
Reversi* ptr = this;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a pretty poor clone function. It doesn't actually clone anything.

Comment: OU Oh yeah! Tell Prof. Dolan Elijah says hello. :)

Comment: @erip I'll be sure to do that! I'm kinda sad that he only teaches up to 2401. He's an amazing Prof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `this` is `const Reversi*` inside the *const* member function. You can use a non-const member function,

```
game* Reversi::clone() {
    Reversi* ptr = this;
    return ptr;
}
```

or change the type of `ptr` to `const Reversi*`,

```
const game* Reversi::clone() const {
    const Reversi* ptr = this;
    return ptr;
}
```

BTW: Your code just make a copy of the pointer `this`, doesn't copy the content at all. That means the returned pointer will just point to the same object. You might want,

```
game* Reversi::clone() const {
    Reversi* ptr = new Reversi(*this); // use copy ctor here
    return ptr;
}
```

Note when you make a copy from `this` the member function could be `const`. This seems more reasonable because a clone method shouldn't change the status of the original object in general.

Comment: In your 3rd sample, the method can be made `const`, and it probably should be.

Comment: That's it! I cant believe I didn't even think of using new.. Thank you sir.